# Is it possible for a git hook to overwrite itself?

Tags: git

Let's assume I have a `post-merge` script which is also stored somewhere else in the repository. I want the hooks to upgrade themselves to the latest version.

Why? The main reason behind this is that hook scripts could also be deployed with a single push without accessing multiple servers and deploying code manually on each server. Hook scripts are dependent of db schema which might be subject to change.

In this scenario a lock is put on `.git/hooks/post-merge` so it can not be overwritten the easy way.

If I used another hook to update the script, such as `pre-merge`, it would succeed, but `pre-merge` does not know about the latest `post-merge` script yet at that point, it would be one commit behind.

Any idea for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Found a possible cure.

At the end of the script, open an independent process that will do the overwriting job. Pass it the PID of `post-merge`, so it can continuously check whether the `post-merge` script is still running. If not, it updates the script to the latest version and exits.